# Why doesn't .attr("checked", true) work in Jquery 1.7 and up

Tags: jquery

**this code works in jQuery, ver. 1.6**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="sameName" />
<input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="sameName" />
<input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="sameName" />

$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("checked") === true) {
        var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $(this).attr("name") + "']";
        $(group).attr("checked", false);
        $(this).attr("checked", true);
    } else {
        $(this).attr("checked", false);
    }
});​
```

BUT if I change the code using new methods of jQuery 1.7 it wont work? why? thanks for yr time :

```
$("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr("checked") === true) {
        var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $(this).attr("name") + "']";
        $(group).attr("checked", false);
        $(this).attr("checked", true);
    } else {
        $(this).attr("checked", false);
    }
});​
```

Comment: $(group).attr("checked", "checked"); and there is also .prop() function for this. please check the jQuery doc.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. If I read this correctly it says: when clicked checkbox is checked, keep it checked and uncheck all others. If it is unchecked, uncheck it again. (?) I suppose you are simulating radiobuttons using checkboxes?

Comment: @c_click that's correct mister. It's all good now!thanks to Blazemonger and wirey :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

attr returns a string.  You should be using [.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set the checked property for jQuery 1.6+

```
$("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $(this).attr("name") + "']";
        $(group).prop("checked", false);
        $(this).prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $(this).prop("checked", false);
    }
});​
```

From jQuery .prop() docs

> The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method.

Answer (score 7):

Use `.prop('checked',true)` instead of `.attr`.

http://api.jquery.com/prop

Also, `if ($(this).attr("checked") === true)` can be shortened to simply

```
if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your code is wrong.
.on() event want container of the elements.

So your **HTML** code should look like this:

```
<div id="chkContainer">
    <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="sameName" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="sameName" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="sameName" />
</div>
```

and **JAVASCRIPT** function like this:

```
$('#chkContainer').on('click', 'input:checkbox', function() {
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
        var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $(this).attr("name") + "']";
        $(group).attr("checked", false);
        $(this).attr("checked", true);
    } else {
        $(this).attr("checked", false);
    }
});
```

This is an example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/5xDzv/1/

Comment: Not necessarily.  Click can be bound using `$(element).on('click',function(){});` if the elements aren't dynamic and exists at the time of binding